# How to create a Certificate Authority as a trusted certificate to all?

Tags: security, openssl, certificate-authority

We can create our own Certificate Authority and issue a certificate to our server. But the browsers doesn't recognize it as a trusted one. Yes we can configure our browsers to trust our certificate. But how can we make our certificate as a universally trusted one like VeriSign or other trusted certificates?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: As LaJmOn said, you can get certificates issued for free from [StartCom](https://www.startcom.org/), [CAcert](http://www.cacert.org/) and [Let’s Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). While they ***issue*** for free, they may charge for revocation because that's where the cost lies.

Comment: And to answer the question in the title (*"How to create a Certificate Authority as a trusted certificate to all?"*), you have to join various Trusted Root programs. For that, see [how to become a member of root ca program](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+become+a+member+of+root+ca+program).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is to obtain a trusted certificate from a Certificate Authority (CA) due to the necessity of a Trust Chain.

There are several free sources like:

https://www.startssl.com/

Also, starting Fall 2015 there will be a free service to obtain trusted certs from
**Let's Encrypt**.

https://letsencrypt.org/

> Let’s Encrypt is a free, automated, and open certificate authority
>   brought to you by the Internet Security Research Group (ISRG),
>   including the Electronic Frontier Foundation, Mozilla, Cisco, and Akamai.