# Encryption Method using md5 hash and triple Des encryption in angular 7

Tags: javascript, c#, encryption, angular7, md5

I want to implement the same encryption with angular7,

The below function is in C#, I tried crypto-js but its not giving me the same results.

using System.Security.Cryptography;

```
    public static string Encrypt(string PlainText, string SecretKey)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] keyArray;
            byte[] toEncryptArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PlainText);

            var hashMD5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            keyArray = hashMD5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SecretKey));
            hashMD5.Clear();

            var triDESProv = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            triDESProv.Key = keyArray;
            triDESProv.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            triDESProv.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            var cTransform = triDESProv.CreateEncryptor();
            byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);
            triDESProv.Clear();
            string encText = Convert.ToBase64String(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length);
            return encText;
        }
        catch
        {
            return "ERROR";
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you configuring and using crypto-js? Also, why MD5 and 3DES? Both are considered insecure.

Comment: Why are you doing this stuff client side? What's it for? The problem with doing it client side is you expose the key to your client, which makes it not very useful for keeping things from the client.

Comment: `tried crypto-js but its not giving me the same results`  maybe you could share the JS code too, we cannot read your monitor. Next - you are using not really safe parameters - MD5 for key stretching, 3DES with partial key,  ECB mode. Really consider if using the default TLS (https)  wouldn't cover your requirements much better

Comment: "SecretKey" will no longer be a secret if you implement this in browser-based JS code. What's the actual use case here? Normally just using HTTPS to encrypt your _connection_ ought to be sufficient to protect the data in transit.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of the algorithm you implemented, why not just install [libsodium-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31086952/how-to-create-a-certificate-authority-as-a-trusted-certificate-to-all) in C#, and [sodium-plus](https://github.com/paragonie/sodium-plus) in JavaScript, and use `crypto_secretbox()`?

Libsodium's secretbox is more secure than the code you posted above for the following reasons:

- [MD5 is considered insecure](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/19906/43688).
- [Triple-DES is inferior to AES](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/26181/43688).
- [ECB mode is dangerous](https://blog.filippo.io/the-ecb-penguin).
- [Unauthenticated encryption is dangerous](https://tonyarcieri.com/all-the-crypto-code-youve-ever-written-is-probably-broken).

In every single way, secretbox is more secure. Support for libsodium is also [near-ubiquitous](https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/bindings_for_other_languages).

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on the subject but I was able to solve it

.NET - C#

```
private static readonly string key = "password";
    public static string Encriptar(string texto)
    {            
        byte[] keyArray;
        byte[] Arreglo_a_Cifrar = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(texto);
        byte[] ivArray = new byte[8];
        //Algoritmo MD5
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashmd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        //se guarda la llave para que se le realice hashing
        keyArray = hashmd5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
        hashmd5.Clear();

        Array.Copy(keyArray, 0, ivArray, 0, 8);

        //Algoritmo 3DES
        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider
        {
            Key = keyArray,
            Mode = CipherMode.ECB,
            Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
            IV = ivArray
        };
        //se empieza con la transformación de la cadena
        ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateEncryptor();
        byte[] ArrayResultado = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(Arreglo_a_Cifrar,0, Arreglo_a_Cifrar.Length);
        tdes.Clear();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(ArrayResultado, 0, ArrayResultado.Length);
    }
```

Angular - CryptoJS

```
encriptarDatos(valor: string) {

 var key = CryptoJS.MD5(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(environment.keyHash));
 var iv = {...key};
 iv.sigBytes = 8;
 var mode = CryptoJS.mode.ECB;
 var encrypted = CryptoJS.TripleDES.encrypt(valor, key, { iv, mode }).toString();
 console.log('DATO ENC:'+encrypted);

 return encrypted;
}
```

its very important that  **IV**(initilization vecctor) must be part of the key and must be the same size in both framewors(Net - Angular)

*My password was 10 characters long and i dont test another size*

Help links:

[CryptoJS-encryptUsingTripleDES](https://stackblitz.com/edit/encryption-decryption-triple-des-angular?file=src%2Fapp%2Fencryption.service.ts)

[Using UTF-8 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52719446/why-i-get-different-md5-hash-from-c-sharp-to-js)

[Net TripleDES](https://www.demo2s.com/csharp/csharp-tripledes-clear.html)